# set title to listview in tabbed activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created tabbed activity with two tab (edittext in tab1,listview in tab2),and I pass data in tab1 to listview in tab2, how to set title for listview

please help

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="store.exercise.com.store.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment one:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

SendMessage SM;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button btnPassData = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPassData);
    final EditText inData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inMessage);
    btnPassData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SM.sendData(inData.getText().toString().trim());
        }
    });

}

interface SendMessage {
    void sendData(String message);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        SM = (SendMessage) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Error in retrieving data. Please try again");
    }
}
}
```

fragment two :

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

protected void displayReceivedData(String message) {
    arrayList.add(message);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

my ViewPagerAdapter :

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = null;
        if (position == 0) {
            title = " مهمة جديدة ";
        } else if (position == 1) {
            title = " المهام ";
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by title? put title where? title on listview? i dont get it, maybe u ask for title on toolbar/actionBar?

Comment: title for listview

Comment: can you add the xml code for the activity that is hosting the tabbed view

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the following on your `activity_view.xml` where you have your viewpager

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/center_section_tab_bar_header_height"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in your activity class add the following line to setup the viewpager with the tab layout header

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(yourviewpager);
```

after which it sets up the header for your tabs as mentioned in your code